# String Format CPF no Android

Tags: java, android, string, formatação

Eu tenho uma variável CPF que é preenchida com um valor que vem do banco de dados
(`11122233344`). Antes de dar `setText()`, preciso que seja formatada em `111.222.333-44`. Como poderia fazer isto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olha fiz assim pode não ser o melhor jeito mais ajuda, o exemplo que fiz foi no eclipse mas em java, é o mesmo jeito no android, sei porque já fiz lá, mas claro desconsidere a parte do static o main da classe, fiz esse exemplo básico porque agora não estou com uma ide android studio.

```
public class Teste {

    private static String CPF ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cpf= "12345678910";
        // 123.456.789-10
        setCPF(cpf.substring(0,3)+"."+cpf.substring(3,6)+"."+cpf.substring(6,9)+"-"+cpf.substring(9,11));

        System.out.println("CPF:"+getCPF());
    }

    public static String getCPF() {
        return CPF;
    }

    public static void setCPF(String cPF) {
        CPF = cPF;
    }

}
```

Como o cpf sempre será padrão os valores, você não terá problema com substring, como pode ver acima pro teste que fiz, eu recebi o numero de cpf não formatado em uma String, depois que fiz isso peguei cada parte do cpf usando substring e fui concatenando já formatando e setando no cpf...

Comment: ninja ! funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 2):

Compartilho da resposta dos colegas, só coloco um ponto a ser considerado.
Em algum momento o CPF pode ser numérico e vir sem os zeros a esquerda, então sugiro verificar primeiro se temos 11 dígitos, para evitar uma exceção ao tentar acessar o ponto 11 com o substring.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
 public static String formatarCPF(String cpf){
    String cpfCompleto = StringUtils.leftPad(cpf, 11, '0');
    return cpfCompleto.substring(0,3)+"."+cpfCompleto.substring(3,6)+"."+cpfCompleto.substring(6,9)+"-"+cpfCompleto.substring(9,11);
}
```

Caso não tenha acesso ao StringUtils do Apache Commons, pode fazer essa função manualmente:

```
 public static String leftPad(String texto, Integer tamanho, Character caracter){
    if(texto.length() < tamanho){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(texto);
        for(int cont = 0; cont < (tamanho-texto.length()); cont ++){
            sb.insert(0, caracter);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return texto;
}
```

Acredito que assim você vai evitar erros, que possam vir a surgir.

Answer (score 1):

a função que o Rogers passou, funcionou perfeitamente.

editei e ficou assim para android:

```
public static String cpf_formatado(String cpf) {
        cpf = cpf.substring(0,3)+"."+cpf.substring(3,6)+"."+cpf.substring(6,9)+"-"+cpf.substring(9,11);
        return cpf;
    }
```